# How do I get puppet to load other policy files in the manifest directory?

Tags: puppet

How do I get puppet to load other policy files in the manifest directory?

It loads site.pp fine, but I would like to load a couple others I have in the directory and it is not loading them with a default install. I realize modules may be a better approach, and I may end up doing that, but for now I just want to logically separate the configuration into separate files. This information is difficult to find in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your other files in the same directory, you can toss something like this into your site.pp:

```
import "someotherfile.pp"
import "classes/*"
import "definitions/*"
```